# Mapstruct Optional into Optional

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to map a optional into another one.

I did the following but I get an error:

`Optional<User> does not have an accessible constructor`

```
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE )
public interface UserMapper {
    Optional<User> map (Optional<UserModel> userModel);
}
```

How can I map a optional into another?

Thanks

Comment: Does `User` have an accessible constructor?

Comment: @MichaelWelch Yes, it works fine without the optional

Answer (score 0):

Optional is not yet supported

see this issue : https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/2874